# Using the libsndfile library to read a WAV file in C++

Tags: c++, libsndfile

I am using libsndfile in C++ to read a WAV file. There are two points I don't understand:

1. How can I get the "Bits per sample" value for the WAV file in question? I read the documentation at the website http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html, but I didn't find a member for "Bits per sample" in the SF_INFO struct.
2. Using the WAV file, how can I create the data to use to draw vectors for describing the sound data, read by function `sf_readf_float()` in library sndfile.h? Is there any method to do this?

Comment: Please re-word the 2nd item, as it really it is not very clear how the `sf-readf_float()` function plays into what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

The format field will give you the BPS. For e.g.: SF_FORMAT_PCM_16.

The sf_readf_float will convert the sample into the -1.0 to 1.0 range no matter the bps of the input sound. You only have to take care that about the audio channels. If the audio has 2 channels and you read 4 floats, you will have:

```
sample-1 of left channel
sample-1 of right channel
sample-2 of left channel
sample-2 of right channel
```

Then, to draw the point you must convert the [-1.0;1.0] to the viewport height. For e.g. if viewport is at Y=20 and the height is 300px, the formula is:

```
PY = (int)(20.0 + (sample_value / 2.0 + 0.5) * 300.0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still don't understand :(. Firstly, When I print member format, it's 65538, but SF_FORMAT_PCM_16 is 2? What is the BPS here? Secondly, As far I know, if I want to draw the point, I have to convert the data to time-domain signal? Am I right? And the data, which was read by sf_readf_float, is time-domain signal, isn't it?

Comment: @Mauro is right. The format field contains 2 or possibly 3 components. If you bitwise AND it with SF_FORMAT_SUBMASK, you will get SF_FORMAT_PCM_16. You can then write a 'switch (format & SF_FORMAT_SUBMASK)' to get the bits per sample. Of course this is not really valid for may compressed formats.

Comment: @Eric: Oh oh, I get it. Thank you very much :D. whhat about the second? Can you explain to me?

Comment: @user2530847: You use sf_readf_float to read the samples. It will return the samples count you requested with channel data interleaved. All samples ranges from -1 to 1. Then you use math to convert the sample to a coordinate in your screen. Which details do you need?